# Parsing Markdown formatted text into BBCode With Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to write a Markdown to BBCode parser.
In this example the markdown input is:

```
This is **bold** but this is also **bold**.
This too is **bold** but and so is this**bold**.
```

And the BBCode output I am trying to program is:

```
This is [b]bold[/b] but this is also [b]bold[/b].
This too is [b]bold[/b] but and so is this[b]bold[/b].
```

My code PowerShell:

```
$MarkdownString ={This is **bold** but this is also **bold**.
This too is **bold** but and so is this**bold**.}
```

I removed the `**` and replaced it with `[b]`:

```
$MarkdownString -Replace '\*\*', '[b]' | New-Variable - BBCodeOutput1
```

And then trying to fix the lack of a `\` in the closing tag for BBCode `[\B]`

```
$BBCodeOutput1 -replace '\[b\].*?\[b\]', '\[b\].*?\[\\b\]' | New-Variable -BBCodeOutput2
```

But the replace Operator second parameter field just interprets everything to be literal text and not Regular expression.

I am sooo confused now, the docs say `-Replace` is fully RegEx capable while `Replace()` is not.

PS: Any ideas on how to handle this this task would be so welcome!!

Comment: To add to zett42's helpful answer: a concise summary of the features of the `-replace` operator, notably also with respect to the placeholders you can use in the replacement operand, can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a single `-replace` operation with a capture group:

```sh
$MarkdownString = @'
This is **bold** but this is also **bold**.
This too is **bold** but and so is this**bold**.
'@

$MarkdownString -replace '\*\*(.+?)\*\*', '[b]$1[/b]'
```

**Output:**

```text
This is [b]bold[/b] but this is also [b]bold[/b].
This too is [b]bold[/b] but and so is this[b]bold[/b].
```

**Explanation:**

`(...)` defines a [capture group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions). Its captured value (the sub string between two occurences of `**`) is then referred to in the substitute using the placeholder `$1` which stands for the 1st capture group.

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2XdQlb/2) for detailed explanation and the ability to play around with the RegEx.

**Notes:**

- [PowerShell 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) contains a [`ConvertFrom-Markdown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-markdown?view=powershell-7.2) command which could be the basis for a more robust Markdown-to-BBCode converter.
- If you need something even more powerful, there are also Markdown parsers for .NET which could be used from PowerShell as well. E. g. [markdig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig).

Comment: What a pretty example, I was looking for something like `$1` placeholder so badly I just gave it up on it. Thanks allot for this example. I am gonna expremiment with it allot. As for your suggestion, I am mostly using these implementations as an excuse to learn programming in Powershell but I will take a look at your links for sure. Thanks!